# php loop mysqli_fetch_array - can it be flexible as normal loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I mean when I use normal loop,  it can set the start of $i = 0;  or $i = any value that I want.  But,Is it possible to loop through fetch array   be set the start row? for example, if I want to start  from third row of database (not start from first row).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM slice_img ORDER BY id";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<div style='width:627px; margin:auto; padding-bottom: 5%;' class='container zeroBorder'>";
            $text = $data['gen_number'];

                $subfile = substr($text, ($i*2), 2);
                echo '<img src="folder'.$data['id'].'/crop'.$subfile.'.jpg" class="zeroBorder" border="0" />';

            echo "</div>";
        }
```

and Do I need to use the fetch $id instead of $i ? the above code, you can notice the echo img src folder fetch$id, actually I would like to write folder.$i  but I don't have normal loop for.

Comment: you could set your own counter outside the loop and increment within the loop - then use that counter value to process rows accordingly or set the `folder.$i`

Comment: if you don't want the first two rows of your result, why don't you just skip them in your query? mysql has a lot of options for data retreival, and `OFFSET` should do the trick, whereas even (slightly) improving performance since less data has to be transferred.

Comment: ok I will use SELECT LIMIT then fetch

Answer (score 2):

Use [`mysqli_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to jump to the row you want to start at.

```
mysqli_data_seek($result, 2);
```

Row numbers start at 0, so this will go to the 3rd row.